How should i manage production API keys vs Development API keys as android developer?
I've been working on this app, right? And it's been quite the journey with all these different APIs involved - Map API keys, AdMob stuff, and Firebase bits. But here's the kicker: when I'm developing, I need to use these test APIs and keep Firebase out of the mix, which means a lot of manual tweaking. Then, when it's time to roll out the final version, I have to switch everything over to the production APIs and bring Firebase back into play, again, manually. It's honestly getting on my nerves because sometimes I forget to remove those test APIs, and chaos ensues. As someone who's still pretty fresh to Android development, I could really use some tips on how to streamline this process. Anyone got some advice?
Here is an exmaple of how do i manage admob ids :
<!-- production ids -->

<string name="ad_unit_banner">ca-app-45s4d54</string>
<string name="ad_unit_interstitial">ca-app-45s4d54</string>

<!-- Test Ids  -->

<string name="ad_unit_banner">ca-56sd556s</string>
<string name="ad_unit_interstitial">ca-56sd556s</string>

Now in the above code i manualy comment that i dont need. This is just to give you an idea of how crumlbed my code is currently.
Thanks a bunch!

You can separate in the build.gradle script those values, by using [flavors][1] and use same key with different value for different output flavors:
productFlavors {
        develop {
            dimension "develop"
            applicationIdSuffix '.develope'
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "")

        }
        production {
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "")

        }
    }

You can access BASE_URL in Android code via BuildConfig.BASE_URL

You can use Sina's approach but productFlavor is supposed to be used for a special version of the app that is different than the regular version.  Since your difference is key values, use Build Types instead if you're going that way.  But ideally you should be storing your keys in a secure server like firebase or continuous integration.  At runtime you fetch the values using your firebase or CI sdk ie setValue("prod_key").

Based on your current example, the simplest thing to do would be to create a debug version of strings.xml with the same keys that will automatically be used for debug (dev) builds.
Current: main/res/values/strings.xml
<!-- production ids -->

<string name="ad_unit_banner">ca-app-45s4d54</string>
<string name="ad_unit_interstitial">ca-app-45s4d54</string>

<!-- Test Ids  -->

<string name="ad_unit_banner">ca-56sd556s</string>
<string name="ad_unit_interstitial">ca-56sd556s</string>

New: main/res/values/strings.xml (default, production)
<!-- production ids -->

<string name="ad_unit_banner">ca-app-45s4d54</string>
<string name="ad_unit_interstitial">ca-app-45s4d54</string>

Add: debug/res/valeus/strings.xml (debug, dev)
<!-- Test Ids  -->

<string name="ad_unit_banner">ca-56sd556s</string>
<string name="ad_unit_interstitial">ca-56sd556s</string>

When you build for debug the debug strings will be used. When you build for release the default strings will be used.
